# How to use post method in WebView in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, post, webview, http-post

I want to make a post request with a JSON Formatted data set in webView in Flutter.
Couldn't find the way out here.
I already tried the [flutter_inappwebview 4.0.0+4](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) but no luck so far. Here is my code snippet:

```
InAppWebView(
          initialHeaders: header,
          initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
            debuggingEnabled: true,
          )),
          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
            webView = controller;
            webView.postUrl(
                url: url,
                postData: utf8.encode(postData.toString()));
          },
          onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
            setState(() {
              this.url = url;
            });
          },
          onLoadStop:
              (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
            setState(() {
              this.url = url;
            });
          },
          onProgressChanged:
              (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
            setState(() {
              this.progress = progress / 100;
            });
          },
        ),
```

Here `header` and `postdata` both are JSON formatted data set.
Is there any way to figure this out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67948632/1140304